# What should I use to create a cross-platform cmd tool for JavaScript developers

Tags: javascript, command-line

I am writing a JavaScript API and I have come to a situation where I would need to create command line commands for developers to use. However, I am not sure how should I do it (Powershell vs Bash), maybe using Java or C#?

If you are making a JavaScript library, what technology would you use for command line tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use Javascript itself, since your API already uses it?

On *NIX systems, there are tools such as [jsc](https://svn.webkit.org/wiki/JSC) that allow you to evaluate Javascript code from the command line. And of course, Windows has [cscript](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff920171%28WS.10%29.aspx).

Comment: @rFactor, code run under `cscript` has access to the [FileSystemObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2z9ffy99.aspx), but it seems that code run under `jsc` can only read from `stdin`.

Comment: And since many devs use Linux, I can't access their filesystem with jsc. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: @rFactor, yup, I think [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/) can do it. There's [an example](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla/source/js/rhino/examples/unique.js) that uses the `File` class.

Answer (score 1):

It would be perfect to use JS to create command line tools, since all your project will be in JS. One way to do it is to compile Google V8 JS engine.

Another common language for CL tools is Python. It is also scripting and portable language.

Comment: Can I read and create files on the system with a V8 engine somehow?